# Using RegExp with more than one conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code:

```
Playlist.aggregate([
    $match: {
        $or: [{genre: new RegExp(["Pop", "Indie"], 'i')}]
    }
]).exec(function(err, playlists){
    console.log(playlists);
});
```

The problem is that it returns an empty array, but when I delete one of the conditions inside `RegExp`(Pop/Indie) it returns correcly.

What am I doing wrong in the RegExp? How can I fix this?

Comment: The first argument to `new RegExp()` has to be a string. It's converting the array to a string, which results in `"Pop,Indie"`

Comment: @Barmar How can I fix this using a var that contains the values?

Comment: `array.join("|")` will do it.

Comment: @Barmar It worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an alternation in a single pattern:

```
Playlist.aggregate([
    $match: {
        $or: [{genre: new RegExp("Pop|Indie", 'i')}]
    }
]).exec(function(err, playlists){
    console.log(playlists);
});
```

But, instead of using `RegExp`, you might want to use a regex literal if you expect your pattern to be constant.

Comment: Hello, I tried to put the values in a var, how I can do this with a var that contains the values "Pop" and "Indie"?

Comment: Read Barmar's comment.